# Programmatically control Amazon Echo

Tags: amazon-echo

I want to programatically call web services to control my Amazon Echo. More specifically, I want to control home automation devices linked to the Echo. For instance, I want to turn an electrical outlet on and off using C# code.

Can this be done? If so, can anyone point me to the API where I can start?